# Jquery: Cross-domain ajax 'POST' with laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel, cross-domain, cors

I'm trying to do an ajax 'POST' on laravel server from another domain from jquery.My laravel Route consists of the codes below:

```
Route::post('auth', function(){
$data = Input::get('username');
return Response::json($data->toArray())->setCallback(Input::get('callback'),JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
});
```

My client is from different server, and the JQuery ajax 'POST' is:

```
function authUser(appId){
var data = '{"username": "' + appId + '"}';
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:8080/auth",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    processData: false,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    CrossDomain:true,
    async: false,
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { //Add these parameters to display the required response
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
});
}
```

I am getting **405 Method Not Allowed** in header response

What is the solution for this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it myself by changing the data type to **json** and adding headers in apache.

## JQuery function:

```
function authUser(appId){
    var data = '{"username": "' + appId + '"}';
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8080/auth",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        processData: false,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        CrossDomain:true,
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { //Add these parameters to display the required response
            alert(xhr.status);
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

## The headers in Apache are:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Content-Type, Content-Range, Content-Disposition, Content-Description"
```

I know the CORS in Headers for Access-Control-Allow-Origin to "*" voids the security but if someone needs the solution it's write up there.

Comment: This is wrong. If you want to do ajax post requests from another domain then you should just do an ajax request asking for a csrftoken then pass it back with the ajax post request

Comment: Is json.stringify needed? If i remember correctly laravel will parse json from all requests so you dont need to stringify your data. Maybe even thats the cause of method not allowed error