# How to send Cross Domain Ajax POST with Laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, post

I am trying to send a cross-domain post call using AJAX from one of my Laravel sites, to another.

The other topic I saw addressed the first issue I was running into with Access Control headers: [Jquery: Cross-domain ajax 'POST' with laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27311091/jquery-cross-domain-ajax-post-with-laravel)

I am getting a 419 error, implying that I am not using a CSRF token, but with either token I use (local token or other domain token) it doesn't work.

```
var CSRF_TOKEN = {{ csrf_token() }};
$.ajaxSetup( { headers : { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN' : CSRF_TOKEN } } );

var tracking_id = "{{ isset( $tracking_id ) ? $tracking_id : 'test-20' }}";
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'https://example.com/beacon',
    crossDomain: true,
    data: { 'tracking_id': tracking_id },
    success: function(responseData, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log( 'Click!' );
    },
    error: function (responseData, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log( responseData );
    }
});
```

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not a *clear problem statement*. What happens? What errors are reported? Look at the Network tab of the develop tools in your browser. Do you get the request you expect? Do you get the response you expect?

Comment: "Cross Domain Ajax POST with Laravel" — You don't. Ajax requests are sent by JavaScript in the browser. You might respond to the request with Laravel, but you wouldn't send the request with it.

Comment: "implying that I am not using a CSRF token, but with either token I use (local token or other domain token)" — The site you are making the request to is going to care about its CSRF token … but the point of CSRF tokens is to prevent requests being triggered across domains, but do you have an end point you are making an Ajax request to protected against CSRF?

Comment: `crossDomain: true,` doesn't do anything unless you are making a same origin request that gets an HTTP redirect to a different origin. It is probably pointless in your code.

Comment: @Quentin I did include the error code and what it means. I'm aware that Laravel doesn't make the calls but it was just how I worded the title. I used the CSRF token from the other site and this still gave me the 419 error in response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excluding the route in VerifyCsrfToken.php would be your easiest bet. You can then make a middleware or some other means to restrict the request by ip, oauth, etc.

Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/csrf#csrf-excluding-uris

Comment: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://mydomain1.com/api/user/register' from origin 'http://api.mydomain2.es' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: You will have to update your content security policy in order to accept the request from another domain. This is a server config issue https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP

Comment: but i have to fix it on the server? how?
by the way i make it work, change my data sent from json to string as params... idk why